# Autenticar servicio externo con firebase utilizando el credenciales del usuario activo

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-auth, firebase-storage

Tengo una aplicacion en reactj integrada con firebase y firebase authentication. La autenticacion la tengo funcionando con email/password y todo funciona perfecto.

Ahora bien, me vi en la necesidad de crear una  API en .NET para poder generar reportes PDF con la data que esta en firebase y me preguntaba como puedo hacer para autorizar la consulta a firebase utilizando la misma autenticacion del usuario.

Como son 2 aplicaciones diferentes, necesito realizar consultas a firebase con las credenciales activas del usuario.

Alguna idea de como lograrlo?

Answer (score 1):

Si tan solo hubiera buscado mejor no hubiera preguntado. Para esto existe la function [getTokenId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtoken) que permite autenticar a una aplicacion de tercero con las credenciales y rol del usuario activo de la aplicacion.

Para obtener el token, solo tienes que acceder a el al momento del signIn:

```
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, async x=>{
      if(x) {
        const token = await x.getIdToken(); // <-- token para autenticar el servicio externo
    }
});
```